# Postgres jsonb object IN array of json objects

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

Say for example I have a table named user with login column with jsonb type
and the record looks like this:

```
user
name  | login
-------------
test1 | {"byDate":[{"date":"2020-01-01"},{"date":"2020-01-02"},{"date":"2020-01-03"},]}
test2 | {"byDate":[{"date":"2020-01-02"},{"date":"2020-01-03"},{"date":"2020-01-04"},]}
```

How do I `SELECT` (with `WHERE` clause) to include both date `'2020-01-01'` and `'2020-01-02'`?

For one date, I can do:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM "user" 
 WHERE "login" @> '{"byDate":[{"date": "2020-01-01"}]}'
```

Can I use some sort of `IN` to select both `'2020-01-01'` and `'2020-01-02'`? Or do I just use OR, ex:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM "user" 
 WHERE "login" @> '{"byDate":[{"date": "2020-01-01"}]}' 
    OR "login" @> '{"byDate":[{"date": "2020-01-02"}]}'
```

I want the result to be an OR product, ex: I use `'2020-01-01'` OR `'2020-01-03'` both `test1` AND `test2` will show up in the result.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please clarify if you need a condition that will only return rows where **both** dates are present or if you want a solution where _at least_ one of the dates is present

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name clarification added.. I need to run an WHERE OR, so at least one of the dates is present.

Comment: your second query will do just that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry, was away for a couple of days, and now back to this project.. What I do not like about my second query, is that if I have a few months (or even a year) worth of date.. it will become a long line of query.. even though I would be constructing the query programmatically, I can't help but wonder if there is a shorter way to do it..

Answer (score 1):

You can use an EXISTS condition:

```
select *
from the_table
where exists (select *
              from jsonb_array_eleements(login -> 'byDate') as x(d)
              where x.d ->> 'date' in ('2020-01-01', '2020-01-02))
```

But your OR solution using `@>` will most probably be more efficient.

Comment: I actually need an OR (at least one).. I am weighing whether to use the OR condition multiple times (like in my original post) or do the solution from Barbaros' answer.. thanks

Comment: @GlenK: there is another solution using EXISTS that might be more efficient than using a CROSS JOIN and DISTINCT

Answer (score 1):

One option would be using a query with `jsonb_array_elements()` function

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.*
  FROM "user" u
 CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(login->'byDate') j
 WHERE j->>'date' IN ('2020-01-01','2020-01-02')
```

which contains `IN` operator.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=2b691819c3b27227fa9e470dd66ba8a7)</kbd>

Comment: I understood "*to include both date*" as both values need to be present in the list, not just one (which the IN would do).

Comment: well @a_horse_with_no_name , I understood *using IN operator whether contains both or single literals* in the list :) . Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `(login->>'byDate')::jsonb` can be simplified to `login->'byDate'` and I think two `@>` conditions with an `OR` would be more efficient that unnesting all elements with a cross join

Comment: thank you @a_horse_with_no_name , converted to `login->'byDate'` .

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan this is giving me the result that I need.. thanks